# JSON Connection string configuration

Tags: sql, json, json.net, database-connection, connection-string

In the app settings JSON file I am passing through a connection string which contains the name of my server
' .\SQL2017 '

I recieve the following warning in error list when entering the server name verbaitam as so in the connection string

'Invalid escape sequence'

When I then run the 'dotnet ef database update' command in the terminal I get the error

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not parse the JSON file.

When I take away the .\ from the connection string to remove the warning for 'Invalid escape sequence I get passed the error above and am then faced with the error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is conf
> igured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I am sure that the rest of my connection string properties are correctly entered with no warnings but I am not sure how to format the server name in the connection string in a JSON format so that it can accept without any errors

Comment: Use forward-slash instead - `./SQL2017`, or encode it - `.%5CSQL2017`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the backslash to escape it:

`.\\SQL2017`